# What can I add to this regex to make it also seperate the string by an underscore in Java?

Tags: java, regex

So I have this regex that does what I need it to for the most part, or so I thought..
`String[] part = str.split("\\b");`
This will take a string such as " int(x,y) " and separate it into 6 new strings. 
1. int
2. (
3. x
4. ,
5. y
6. )
BUT I just realized that my regex is not doing this with underscores? For example the string " ret_urn" is not split at all. Is it possible to add an "AND" to my regex to include underscores?

Comment: Well, you could add `|_`, i.e. `\b|_` which means "match a word boundary _or_ an underscore". You might also want to explore https://www.regular-expressions.info/ a little to learn more about regular expressions in general.

Comment: One question though: it seems as if you're trying to parse code using regular expressions. If so then please note that this is bound to fail or get at least very complicated. Code normally is an irregular domain which are no good fit regular expressions.

Comment: @Thomas I understand that. This is just one very tiny part of my lexical analyzer. I was about to turn the project in until I noticed that my test cases with underscores failed. Everything else worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below to get the result you expect with an or,

```
String str = "int(x,y)_ret_urn";
str.split("\\b|((?<=_)|(?=_))");
```